# logrotate dateformat seems not supporting %H:%M:%S

Tags: date-format, logrotate

I am newer to logrotate. when the configure comes to the property "dateformat",it seems that logrotate doesn't support strftime "%H" . here is the config:

```
{
    daily
    rotate  2
    size 3M
    missingok
    notifempty
    dateext
    dateformat -%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S
    ...
}
```

the rotated file format tend to look like : uwsgi_dev.log-20150630_%H:%M:%S, but I want the exact "hour minutes and seconds".

thanks

Answer (score 22):

Support for `%H` was added in version [3.9.0](https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate/blob/master/ChangeLog.md#390---2015-04-03), for `%M` and `%S` - [3.9.2](https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate/blob/master/ChangeLog.md#392---2016-01-20) In earlier versions, logrotate did not support strftime "%H:

> dateformat format_string: Specify the extension for dateext using the notation similar to strftime(3) function. Only %Y %m %d and %s specifiers are allowed.

From the logrotate man page http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate

However, you can use `%s` in the dateformat string, which is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01. You can set `dateformat -%Y%m%d-%s`. This will produce unique filenames every time the log is rotated, so you can rotate the file multiple times a day. Unfortunately, the `%s` part will not be easy to read, but you can easily convert it back into a readable date with `perl -e "print scalar(localtime(1451214849))"`.

On some systems, the `date` program allows to do such conversion easily with `date -d @1451214849` (e.g. GNU `date`). On most systems (including e.g. Solaris `date`), you may have luck with syntax like `date -d "1970-01-01 + 1451214849 sec"`. Note that Busybox `date` supports only the `@` trick but not complex expressions of the second example.

Comment: Support for %H was added in version [3.9.0](https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate/blob/master/CHANGES).